# vector<string> is null while some strings having been inserted

Tags: c++, string, vector, cout

I created a `vector<string>` to hold `string`s,but when I `cout<<vec[0]`,I found that nothing was in it.Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
vector<string> vec(10);
string s("123123");
vec.push_back(s);
cout<<vec[0]<<endl;
vector<string>::iterator it=vec.begin();
cout<<*it<<endl;
}
```

Comment: try `cout << vec[10] << endl;`

Comment: What do you think that constructor does?

Comment: push_back does not place a string in the first position. It adds a NEW string to the end of the vector, which you create with 10 empty strings.

Comment: if you want to reserve at least enough memory to hold `n` elements, then use `std::vector<>::reserve(size_type n)` member function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 vector<string> vec(10);
```

This line defines a vector `vec` with **initially ten elements**.

```
vec.push_back(s);
```

This `push_back`'s an **11<sup>th</sup> member**.

```
cout<<vec[0]<<endl;
```

Outputs the **first** element of the `vector`. The one that was value-initialized along with the other first ten ones.

`push_back`, as the name implies, inserts at the back of a container. Try `insert`ing at the beginning like so:

```
vec.insert( vec.begin(), s );
```

That should give you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```c++
vector<string> vec(10);
```

constructs 10 `std::string` instances and puts them into storage. The following `push_back()` call is appending `s` as the *11th* element, not the first.

```c++
vec.push_back(s); // vec.size() now 11 with last element "123123"
```

All the other strings are empty strings.

If you don't use the size constructor, everything works. Or maybe you wanted to reserve memory for 10 objects without constructing them. In that case use `vec.reserve(10)`. It doesn't do much in this case, but for larger ones it can prevent multiple reallocations if the size is known ahead of time.